# dll reference error even if it is added in nopcommerce 3.6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Here I am using nopcommerce 3.6 In which my folder structure is like below

1. plugin is nop.xxx. Its physical path is on MyProject/nop.xxx --> it is on same place where we have Presentation, packages and Libraries.
2. plugin is nop.yyy. Its physical path is on MyProject/Plugins/nop.yyy -> Where we put our all normal plugins

Now issue is in **nop.xxx** plugin because in that two .dll files I have referenced then also when I build it, It gives me error that 
**Are you missing reference of Nop.service?
Are you missing reference of nop.yyy?**

Though in plugin nop.yyy is build successfully.

Note: **nop.xxx and nop.yyy plugins output path are same on presentation/Nop.web/Plugin/Nop.output**

your responces are appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to make copy local true and then clean and build may be helps you... othere wise your is right.....

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.I found solution actually issue is in RESTSharp.dll is of framework 4.5.2 and I am using framework 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I have checked my all referenced dll framework in both plugins.
amoung them RESTSharp dll framework is 4.5.2 but I am using framework 4.5.1.

Thank you